# Error when running a Spring project with MySQL support

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a project and I just added MySQL support to it, along with JPA and others:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    ...
```

I then configured the `application.properties` file as follows:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/spring
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

But then, this error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setConfigurers' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xmlbeam/config/XMLFactoriesConfig
>
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.web.config.SpringDataWebConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/xmlbeam/config/XMLFactoriesConfig

I don't understand very well what's this and why it is happening. I thought Boot was supposed to take care of the main configuration? I even generated a new project with these dependencies as default but the same error persists.

Comment: looks like you dont have dependencies avaliable at runtime. Add   <scope>runtime</scope> to your dependencies and check if that works

Comment: Sadly, nothing changes.

Comment: Please add the full list of dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

The reason behind this was the Java version. I had version 14, o I uninstalled it and installed the latest LTS version, 11

> sudo apt purge openjdk-14*

updated the `pom.xml` to use the same version, then I erased everything generated regarding of configuration and opened it again to generate them again, and everything worked.

Comment: Nice catch... I've switched back from Java 14 to 13 and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Add following properties and try again

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL57Dialect
```

Hope this solve your problem :)

Comment: Hi. The error persists, but I see a warning: `Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found`.

Comment: By the way, the version of MySQL installed is 8.

Comment: See my updated answer. By the way are you using any models or repositories? If you have, you have to properly annotate them.

Comment: I do, and they are.

Comment: Do you have any configuration classes ?

Comment: No, I do not have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210822/discussion-between-codewalter-and-gamofe).

Answer (score 0):

If you have any Service and Data layer. please annotate it with @Repository and @Service annotation

Please go through mkyong java basic tutorials.

[Github Link](https://github.com/mkyong/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-data-jpa-mysql)